# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio automate database job checks

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation

I would like to create a program that will check the jobs running on databases on different servers and alert me when a job fails. I would think that PowerShell would be a good tool in doing this. If anyone has any insight on creating an automation program like this, I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi, have you tried writing/testing anything yet ?

Answer (score 0):

use a ssh cmdline client such as plink.exe to remotely run a bash script on the MySQL server.
the script should be like :

## !/bin/bash

mysql -e "use XXX ; select XXX from XXX inner join XXX on XXX where XXX ...."
use PowerShell to run this plink.exe and get a list of job status saved to a tmp file or variable
cat tmpfile| foreach {if($_.split("`t")[whichever] -match 'whatever'){"dude you are lazy, code it urself."}}